# return database message on successful sql execution using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, adodb

I need to capture sql message upon successful execution of sql statement using vbscript. Here is my code.

```
Public Function ExecuteAPI_String(sql_Statement)
Dim num 
On Error Resume Next
Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute sql_Statement,num,adExecuteNoRecords
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ExecuteSQLStatement_String = Err.description
    objRecordSet.Close
    Err.Clear
Else
    ExecuteAPI_String = num & "records were affected"
    objRecordSet.Close
End If
```

Comment: Would have been helpful if you posted the resulting message you receive from `ExecuteSQLStatement_String` or `ExecuteAPI_String`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the use of `On Error Resume Next` because it will cause any statement that errors to be skipped and set the `Err` object. If you comment out the `On Error Resume Next` you will see the actual error which will be nothing to do with the execution of your SQL query as this line;

```
Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute sql_Statement,num,adExecuteNoRecords
```

isn't a valid statement as the method needs to be surrounded by brackets like this;

```
Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(sql_Statement, num, adExecuteNoRecords)
```

You will also need to make sure that all the values you're passing to the `Execute()` method are valid *(such as `adExecuteNoRecords` being correctly defined)*.

Once you're sure the line is executing correctly, then you can uncomment the `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart. I tried this: and i am getting an error Object required 
`Dim num 
Err.Clear 
Set objRecordSet = connStr.Execute(Sql_Statement, num, ADODB.ExecuteOptionEnum.adExecuteNoRecords) 
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
      ExecuteSQLStatement_String = Err.Description Err.Clear 
Else If isNull(objRecordSet) or objRecordSet.EOF = True Then         ExecuteSQLStatement_String = Null 
Else ExecuteSQLStatement_String = objRecordSet.Fields(colname).Value 
End If 
End If 
objRecordSet.Close 
On Error GoTo 0`